# Falling back on PROMPT mode since _cordovaNative is missing. Expected for Android 3.2 and lower only.

Tags: android, compiler-errors, cordova-3

I have the following **problem**:

When I click on the marker of my map (using **google maps v3**) I get this error:

> "Falling back on PROMPT mode since _cordovaNative is missing. Expected
>   for Android 3.2 and lower only."

How can I fix?

use cordova 3.0.0 and chrome in unsafe mode
thank you very much

Answer (score 7):

If your testing in your browser remove reference to the cordova.js file. i.e remove

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

file from your index.html file.
Add this only when testing your app on the device.